# Difference between SphericalMapping and CubeMapping for environmental reflection in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, geometry, glsl, shader

I'm working with an environmental reflection in OpenGL+GLSL.

I want to reflect the environment around an object in the most accurate way possible.

I found basically two way to do this, one is called SphericalMapping and the other is CubeMapping.

They differ in the shader code but really don't understand what is the difference between them.

Obviously for the cubemapping shader I have 6 images printed on a cube that are needed for the fragment shader to look the right pixel, and for my Spheric mapping shader a single image which is distorted with a photo-retouch software or obtained by taking a photo of a specular reflective sphere.

The drawbacks of spherical mapping seems to be that the camera (and the person which holds it) is always showed in the image and the sampling is non-uniform. What is meant by this latest statement? What is meant by "black-hole" effect in spherical mapping?

I would like to find an interactive demonstration of the differences and drawbacks of these two approaches, it seems like cubemapping is the best, but don't know why.

What is the best of the two especially for a realtime simulation with head tracking in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spheremaps are usually for small, low quality stuff.

> The drawbacks of spherical mapping seems to be that the camera (and the person which holds it) is always showed in the image

We're talking about computer graphics here; there is no real camera, or no real person. Try imagegoogling "spheremap", you won't see anybody in the pictures.

> the sampling is non-uniform

This means that the center of the spheremap has many pixels for a relatively small area, while near the border, you have few pixels for a relatively large area.

Cubemaps are almost always better : you can generate them at runtime easily, it's faster to sample for the hardware, and even though you have 6 textures instead of 1, you can use a lower resolution and still get the same quality.

Comment: Oh thanks! I will keep working with cubemaps, they beat spheremaps in every detail and the shader to write is simpler!